# Как добавить сообщение об ошибке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, mediawiki-api

Подскажите, как добавить в этот фрагмент сообщение об ошибке, тк если в вике не находится нужной статьи приложение падает.

```
elif re.search(r'\Подскажи\b', Message['text']):
    api.messages.send(
        peer_id=Message['peer_id'],
        random_id=Message['random_id'],
        message='Вот, держи! \n\n' + str(wikipedia.summary(Message['text'][9:]))
    )
```

Сами ошибки, сейчас столкнулся с двумя:
Первая если по запросу находит несколько статей на разные темы:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\wikipedia.py", line 389
    lis = BeautifulSoup(html).find_all('li')
UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("html.parser"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

The code that caused this warning is on line 389 of the file C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\wikipedia.py. To get rid of this warning, pass the additional argument 'features="html.parser"' to the BeautifulSoup constructor.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Елена\Desktop\test\рабочая версия.py", line 66, in <module>
    message='Вот, держи! \n\n' +str(wikipedia.summary(Message['text'][9:])))
  File "C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\util.py", line 28, in __call__
    ret = self._cache[key] = self.fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\wikipedia.py", line 231, in summary
    page_info = page(title, auto_suggest=auto_suggest, redirect=redirect)
  File "C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\wikipedia.py", line 276, in page
    return WikipediaPage(title, redirect=redirect, preload=preload)
  File "C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\wikipedia.py", line 299, in __init__
    self.__load(redirect=redirect, preload=preload)
  File "C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\wikipedia.py", line 393, in __load
    raise DisambiguationError(getattr(self, 'title', page['title']), may_refer_to)
wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError: "Устройство" may refer to: 
прибор
Устройство (радиотехника)
землеустройство
порядок
↑
```

Вторая когда запрашиваемую статью не находит:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\wikipedia.py", line 272, in page
    title = suggestion or results[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Елена\Desktop\test\рабочая версия.py", line 66, in <module>
    message='Вот, держи! \n\n' +str(wikipedia.summary(Message['text'][9:])))
  File "C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\util.py", line 28, in __call__
    ret = self._cache[key] = self.fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\wikipedia.py", line 231, in summary
    page_info = page(title, auto_suggest=auto_suggest, redirect=redirect)
  File "C:\Users\Елена\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\wikipedia.py", line 275, in page
    raise PageError(title)
wikipedia.exceptions.PageError: Page id "арараоао" does not match any pages. Try another id!
```

Полный код:

```
import os
from random import randint
from requests import *
import vk
import wikipedia
import re



# Указываем ключи доступа, id группы и версию API
VK_API_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'токен'
VK_API_VERSION = '5.103'
GROUP_ID = ид группы

wikipedia.set_lang("RU")


session = vk.Session(access_token = VK_API_ACCESS_TOKEN)
api = vk.API(session, v = VK_API_VERSION)

# Первый запрос к LongPoll: получаем server и key
longPoll = api.groups.getLongPollServer(group_id = GROUP_ID)
server, key, ts = longPoll['server'], longPoll['key'], longPoll['ts']

while True:
    # Последующие запросы: меняется только ts
    longPoll = post('%s'%server, data = {'act': 'a_check',
                                         'key': key,
                                         'ts': ts,
                                         'wait': 25}).json()


    if longPoll['updates'] and len(longPoll['updates']) != 0:
        for update in longPoll['updates']:
            if update['type'] == 'message_new':
                Object = update['object']#выуживаем из множества update множество object
                Message = Object['message']#выуживаем из множества bject множество message

                print(Message['peer_id'],'\n',Message['from_id'],'\n',Message['text'])
                print ('---------------------------------')
                # Отправляем сообщение
                if Message['text']== 'Команды':
                    api.messages.send(
                    peer_id = Message['peer_id'],
                    random_id = Message['random_id'],
                    message='1.Конь \n2.Пшел \n3.Подскажи'
                    )

                elif Message['text']== 'Конь':
                    api.messages.send(
                    peer_id = Message['peer_id'],
                    random_id = Message['random_id'],
                    message='Нет, Лось'
                    )
                elif Message['text']== 'Пшел':
                    api.messages.send(
                    peer_id = Message['peer_id'],
                    random_id = Message['random_id'],
                    message='Куда?'
                    )
                elif re.search(r'\Подскажи\b',Message['text']):
                     api.messages.send(
                     peer_id = Message['peer_id'],
                     random_id = Message['random_id'],
                     message='Вот, держи! \n\n' +str(wikipedia.summary(Message['text'][9:])))



    # Меняем ts для следующего запроса
    ts = longPoll['ts']
```

Comment: Во-первых, двоеточие после elif

Comment: Никакого двоеточия не надо. Во-вторых "приложение падает" не дает никакой информации, чтобы можно было помочь. Регулярное выражение написано правильно? Что-то кажется, что обратный слеш лишний или что.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо. Нашел решение:

```
elif re.search(r'\Подскажи\b',Message['text']):
                    try:
                        api.messages.send(
                        peer_id = Message['peer_id'],
                        random_id = Message['random_id'],
                        message='Вот, держи! \n\n' +str(wikipedia.summary(Message['text'][9:])))
                    except wikipedia.exceptions.PageError:
                        api.messages.send(
                        peer_id = Message['peer_id'],
                        random_id = Message['random_id'],
                        message='Ничего не нашель :(')
                    except wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError as e:
                        print (e.options)
                        api.messages.send(
                        peer_id = Message['peer_id'],
                        random_id = Message['random_id'],
                        message=(e))
```

Answer (score 1):

заключить в блок try-except, вот так:

```
elif re.search(r'\Подскажи\b',Message['text']):
    try:
       api.messages.send(
                    peer_id = Message['peer_id'],
                    random_id = Message['random_id'],
                    message='Вот, держи! \n\n' +str(wikipedia.summary(Message['text'][9:])))
    except:
        print('Not found')
```

И желательно после except указать какую именно ошибку выдает программа, если она известна. Например, при деление на ноль программа выдает ошибку: `ZeroDivisionError`, значит блок будет выглядеть так:

```
elif какое-то условие:
    try:
        a=5/0
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print('Div by zero')
```

Comment: Тут же `SyntaxError`, выражению `elif` нужно условие. А после `re.search....` не начинается никакой блок.

Comment: @mrEvgenX, спасибо, исправил

Comment: Я бы логику формирования сообщения вынес из вызова `api.messages.send`, потому что это затрудняет чтение кода. К тому же, если бы автор вопроса рассказал нам, что за ошибка у него случилась (скорее всего при вызове `wikipedia.summary` или где-то рядом). То можно было бы именно эту ошибку обернуть в try/except или просто `if` какой-нибудь написать. А писать просто `except:` или `except Exception:` я бы не советовал. Так мы скрываем другие ошибки. А что если api недоступно? Что если проблемы с отправкой сообщения? Мы выдадим `Not found`, а это не то, что хотелось. Правильно в конце замечено.

Comment: Извиняюсь, дополнил вопрос